# Laptop screen not working after repair

Tags: boot, laptop, display, lcd, repair

I own an Asus Vivobook and I had to change the monitor frame -not the LCD screen itself-. All the operations are done, but when I shwitch on my laptop the screen turns on, I can see the "ASUS" logo and then the screen goes black. If I plug in an external monitor everything is fine, it simply seems the LCD screen stops working after the ASUS logo appears.

I went into Windows settings and I cannot find the LCD screen in the listed monitors which is quite weird since I did not change anything in the system configuration and the LCD screen is the same as before, I only changed the frame...I think the LCD screen is plugged in correctly, since I can see the ASUS logo first...

Comment: Take it back to the repair shop.

Comment: Check that the cover-open switch is working. If it shows as having the cover closed, the internal display may be disconnected. Also check for broken traces in the thin plastic cable to the display, particularly right at the connector. A broken trace can sometimes be fixed with conductive paint, as used for car window heater-grid repair.